# Angular 2 or 4 or 5 ng-style with more than 2 conditional outputs

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-template

like an angularjs 1.x how to implement ngstyle for more than 2 conditions?

Angularjs 1.x:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <p ng-style="cond1  ? { color:'green' } : cond2 ? {color: 'blue'} : cond3 ? {color: 'red'} : {color: ''}">Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

Angular-2/4/5: 
In below code darked, gold and green are the variables declared in typescrip.

```
<button class="button" id="btn_status" [ngStyle]="darked?     {backgroundColor:'darked'} : gold?{backgroundColor:'gold'} : green?{backgroundColor:'green'}">
```

Getting Error here,

[image]

Comment: [ngStyle]="{'color':cond1?'green':cond2?'blue':cond3?'red':''}" (all quotes between " are single quotes)

Comment: or [style.color]="cond1?'green':cond2?'blue':cond3?'red':''" (only the first and last are double quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do it like so:

```
<button class="button" id="btn_status" [ngStyle]="{'backgroundColor': darked || gold || green}">
```

Component:

```
darked = null;
gold = null;
green = null;

cond1() {
  if(true) 
    this.darked = 'black'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something like that you're better off making a call to a method. You want to avoid putting large amounts of logic into the template, if at all possible:

```
<button
  class="button"
  id="connection_status"
  [ngStyle]="colorCheck()">
```

And the method then returns the color you require.

```
colorCheck() {
  if (this.darked) {
    return {backgroundColor: 'darked'};
  }
}
```

Or even better since they're all the same class that you're setting:

```
<button
  class="button"
  id="connection_status"
  [style.backgroundColor]="colorCheck()">

colorCheck() {
  if (this.green) {
    return 'green';
  }
  // etc
}
```